# How to change admob position

Tags: android

I want to change positon of admob. I tried to move my admob code to top of my relative layout, but i take unfortunately your application has closed. So how can i do it. Thanks in advice

xml codes :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/web_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_show_stick_height_without_shadow" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/web_view_progress"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/progress_bar_status"
            android:indeterminateOnly="false"
            android:max="100" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/web_view_buttons_divider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ad_bottom_sticky_uppershadow" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/card_show_stick_height"
        android:background="@android:color/black" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/web_view_btn_back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/web_view_margin_1"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/web_view_margin_2"
            android:src="@drawable/stick_btn_back" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/web_view_btn_forward"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/web_view_btn_back"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/web_view_margin_3"
            android:src="@drawable/stick_btn_forward" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/web_view_lay_refresh"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/web_view_btn_forward"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/web_view_margin_4" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/web_view_btn_refresh"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:src="@drawable/stick_btn_refresh"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/loading"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmallInverse"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/loading_spinner_size_small"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/loading_spinner_size_small"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/web_view_btn_share"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/web_view_lay_refresh"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/web_view_margin_5"
            android:src="@drawable/stick_btn_share" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-2128604123953452/6982779835" >
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</LinearLayout>
```

-- This is what i have --
[image]

-- This is what i want --
[image]

Comment: For it, your parent layout should be a `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/web_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_show_stick_height_without_shadow" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/web_view_progress"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/progress_bar_status"
            android:indeterminateOnly="false"
            android:max="100" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/web_view_buttons_divider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ad_bottom_sticky_uppershadow" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black" >
         <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-2128604123953452/6982779835" >
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/card_show_stick_height"
        android:background="@android:color/black" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/web_view_btn_back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/web_view_margin_1"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/web_view_margin_2"
            android:src="@drawable/stick_btn_back" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/web_view_btn_forward"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/web_view_btn_back"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/web_view_margin_3"
            android:src="@drawable/stick_btn_forward" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/web_view_lay_refresh"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/web_view_btn_forward"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/web_view_margin_4" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/web_view_btn_refresh"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:src="@drawable/stick_btn_refresh"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/loading"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmallInverse"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/loading_spinner_size_small"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/loading_spinner_size_small"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/web_view_btn_share"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/web_view_lay_refresh"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/web_view_margin_5"
            android:src="@drawable/stick_btn_share" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```